# Php não quer gravar dados de cadastro no banco de dados

Tags: php

```
<?php
include_once("conexao.php");
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$sql = ("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`nome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ([$nome],[$email],[$senha])");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>



<html>
<head>
<title>Central de Estudos | Cadastro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/java.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("imgs/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <h3 style="font-size: 14px;">CENTRAL DE ESTUDOS | CADASTRO</h3>
    <form class="login-form" name="loginform" method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome"/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha" />
      <button type="hidden" name="entrar" value="cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
      <p class="message"> Desenvolvido por: Marcos A. Massini</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Em `$sql`, troque os `[]` por `{}`. Para confirmar se realmente é este o problema, basta verificar o valor de `$sql` antes e depois da mudança.

Comment: Alterei, mesmo assim não foi

Comment: A minha conexão esta assim.

Comment: <?php
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario = "root";
  $senha = "";
  $dbname = "cadastro";

  $conn = Mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname) or print (mysql_error());

  if(!Mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha)) {
    echo "Error ao conectar";
  }
?>

Comment: E qual foi o resultado ao exibir o valor de `$sql`? Parece que faltam aspas nos valores ali também.

Comment: Nenhum, ele não apresenta nenhum erro, apenas não salva os dados no mysql.

Comment: Não é o erro, mas sim colocar um `var_dump($sql)` no seu código. E você já está em contato comigo aqui.

Comment: Assim tinha entendido outra coisa, ele me printo isso:

Comment: string(105) "INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`nome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES (Marcos Augusto Masini,marcos@gmail.com,81810338)"

Comment: basta corrigir sua consulta para  `$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$senha')";` que vai funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Há pelo menos dois erros no seu código PHP:

1. Recuperar valores na superglobal `$_POST` sem verificar se a requisição tratada pelo servidor é uma POST. Isto é, quando você acessa a página via navegador, este envia uma requisição GET ao servidor e, assim, os valores em `$_POST` não existem, gerando um erro. Se não exibiu as mensagens de erro, é possivelmente porque seu servidor está configurado para tal - o que é muito ruim em um ambiente de desenvolvimento: as mensagens de erros são as melhores amigas do desenvolvedor, pois elas nos dizem o que está errado e nos polpa tempo. Para contornar isso, basta verificar o método da requisição HTTP:

   ```
   <?php

   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

       include_once("conexao.php");

       $nome = $_POST['nome'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $senha = $_POST['senha'];

       ...

   }
   ```
2. A sua consulta SQL está estruturada de forma errada por dois motivos:

   - Está utilizando colchetes (`[]`) no lugar de chaves (`{}`);
   - Não está inserindo devidamente as aspas nos valores;

A forma correta da consulta seria:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`nome`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES ('{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$senha}')";
```

Comment: Opaaaaaaaaaaa, valeu <3, estou aprendendo PHP agora, ai você já viu kkkkk, sempre quando eu for fazer uma coisa do tipo eu uso :      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

Comment: Só quando fizer sentido: tratar requisições HTTP com método POST. Se isso não fez sentido, recomendo estudar o protocolo HTTP antes de estudar PHP.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado